# Открыть изображения в ListView из БД

Tags: java

В БД сохранены ссылки на исображения которые локально хранятся на устройстве. При открытии лист вью  я использую кастомный адаптер который загружает изображения по ссылкам

```
 File filePath = new File(image); //image содержит ссылкуна изображение

                   Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(filePath);
                   final InputStream imageStream;
                   imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
                   selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
```

проблема в том, что оно заметно тупит при прокручивании ленты и переодически вылетает по причине нехватки памяти. Я вынес загрузку изображений в отдельный поток и передаю в него строку image

```
 mt = new MyTask();
 mt.execute(image);

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

 private    Bitmap selectedImage = null;



    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String[] image = params;



            try {
                File filePath = new File(image[0]);
                Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(filePath);
                final InputStream imageStream;
                imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
                selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       // }
        return selectedImage;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);


    }
}
```

Предыдущая проблема решилась но появилась другая. Асин таск получает ссылки по одной штуке, по мере прокручивания, т.е. если на момент открытия лист вью в видимой области 3 изображения, загрузится только одно, остальные только по мере прокрутки. Как решить эту проблему, может есть более правильный сособ?

Comment: используйте библиотеки вроде glide, picasso -они кэшируют изображения, реализуют многопоточную асинхронную загрузку и много другого полезного

Answer (score 0):

Правильный способ состоит в том, чтобы использовать специализированные библиотеки, которые правильно и человечно делают эту работу (подгрузку изображений).

Таких библиотек много, я лично предпочитаю [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Альтернатив достаточно много развелось в последнее время, из них наверное можно выделить  [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) - как одну из наиболее продвинутых.